# Javascript iframe src page adding dynamic input not working

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add input in a div content javascript but it doesn't add

**HTML:**

```
<button onclick="Addcompntn();" class="btn btn-success">Add</button>
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="index.html" allowfullscreen id="if1"></iframe>
```

**Script:**

```
function Addcompntn() {
    var framedeki = document.getElementById('if1').contentWindow.document; 
    $('example').append('<div id="innerdiv" style="color:white;"></div>');
}
```

**index.html**

```
<div id="example" style="z-index:2"> //dynamic data will come here </div>
```

Comment: Is the source of the iframe the same domain as the parent page?

Comment: If it's not on the same domain .. And you don't have access to the `iframe` domain's settings (to change CORS policy) .. It will be impossible to do --  If it's on the same domain and not working . You need to check the CORS policy of your domain and adjust it accordingly.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#:~:text=Cross%2DOrigin%20Resource%20Sharing%20(CORS)%20is%20a%20mechanism%20that,resources%20from%20a%20different%20origin.&text=The%20CORS%20mechanism%20supports%20secure,transfers%20between%20browsers%20and%20servers.

Comment: yes i'm working in the same directory and localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding element to the iframe document body:

```
function Addcompntn() {
    var framedeki = document.getElementById('if1').contentWindow.document;   
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.id = 'innerdiv';
    div.style.color = 'white';    
    framedeki.getElementById('example').append(div);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked successfully and I can configure the div, but how can I add div inside div, not body

Comment: @Muhammed just get element that you need inside iframe and append that div to it. I've updated my answer.